# При чтении файла реализовать перенос строки

Tags: c, windows, файлы

Здравствуйте, необходимо при чтении файла реализовать перенос строки, т.е если длинна строки превышает 60 символы то остальные символы должны быть перенесены на следующую строку. (Строки должны храниться в массиве)

#### Исходный файл:

[in.txt](http://pastebin.com/2ZpipX6G)

```
char text[100][60],buffer[60];

void clear_buffer()
{
    for(int i=0;i<60;i++)
    {
        buffer[i]='\0';             // '/0'- пустой смвол
    }
}
```

#### Обращение к файлу:

```
FILE *in;
in=fopen("in.txt","r+");
int q=0;
```

Собственно, к задаче:

#### Первый вариант:

```
char ch;
int i=0,j=0;
while ((ch=fgetc(in))!=EOF)
{
    text[i][j]=ch;
    j++;
    if(ch=='\n'){j=0;i++;}
    if(j==59){text[i][j]='\n';i++;j=0;}
    printf("%c",ch);
}
```

Выглядит так:

[image: результат]

#### Второй вариант:

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    fgets(buffer,60,in);

    if(buffer[strlen(buffer)-1]!='\0' and buffer[strlen(buffer)-1]!='\n')
    {


        for(int j=0;j<59;j++)
        {
            text[i][j]=buffer[j];
        }
        text[i][59]='\n';
        q++;
        fseek(in,ftell(in)-1,SEEK_SET);
    }
    else
    {
        for(int j=0;j<60;j++)
        {
            text[i][j]=buffer[j];
        }

    }

    clear_buffer();
    //printf("%s",text[i]);

}
```

Результат тот же, происходит некое дублирование....

Предложите пожалуйста Ваши варианты решения этой задачи, т.к у меня почему-то не получается, по-разному пробовал.

Comment: Вместо вашего clear_buffer существует классная функция memset(). Касательно неправильной работы программы - попробуйте отладчиком посмотреть.

Comment: @Илья Из вашего описания на самом деле неясно, что нужно сделать. Как я понимаю, нужно заполнить двумерный символьный массив записями файла. Только остается открытым вопрос: нужно ли добавлять символ новой строки в строку этого массива, если строка файла превосходит длину строки массива. Или же символы новой строки вообще не должны заноситься в массив.

Comment: @Илья То есть если вам нужно организовать просто перенос строки при выводе файла на консоль, то зачем нужны массивы?

Comment: Ссылка на входной файл недоступна без регистрации. Используй [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/), пожалуйста.

Comment: Вывод будет в файл(после некоторой обработки массива), длина строки 60 символов соответсвенно если строка превышает 60 символов то необходима поставить \n и оставшиеся символы дописать в след строку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вам просто нужно вывести на консоль текстовый файл посимвольно, таким образом, чтобы длина строки вывода не превышала 60 знаков, то вы можете сделать это следующим образом. Я надеюсь, что вам программу нужно написать на C++, а не на C.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 60;
    std::ifstream in( "in.txt" );

    char c;
    for ( size_t i = 0; in.get( c ); i %= N )
    {
        if ( c == '\t' ) c = ' ';
        std::cout << c;
        if ( c == '\n' ) i = N;
        else if ( ++i == N  ) std::cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

В программе символы табуляции заменяются пробелами.

Что касается, например, вашего первого фрагмента кода, то заполнение массива никак не связано с выводом на консоль.
Предложение

```
printf("%c",ch);
```

у вас выполняется безусловно.

Если же ваша задача совершенно иная.:) 
И на самом деле 1) вам надо написать программу на C, а не на C++ и 2) вам не надо посимвольно считывать файл, а нужно заполнить массив строками из файла, то программа может выглядеть следующим образом

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 100
#define M 60

int main( void )
{
//  const size_t N = 100, M = 60;
    char text[N][M];

    FILE *in;

    if ( ( in = fopen( "in.txt", "r" ) ) != NULL )
    {
        char buffer[M];
        size_t i = 0;
        int overflow = 0;

        while ( i < N && fgets( buffer + overflow, M - overflow, in ) )
        {
            size_t n = strlen( buffer );

            if ( n + 1 < M || buffer[n-1] == '\n' )
            {
                overflow = 0;
                strcpy( text[i++], buffer );
            }
            else
            {
                overflow = 1;
                char c = buffer[n-1];
                buffer[n-1] = '\n';
                strcpy( text[i++], buffer );
                buffer[0] = c;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Имейте в виду, что если затем вы будете выводить на консоль этот массив строк, то вам нужно будет заменить символы табуляции символами пробела.

Comment: Видно, что пишет не новичок. Однако `std::cout`, если уж комментировать, пишет медленнее, чем даже `python`овский или `perl`овский `print`. Ну и еще  вместо `std::size_t` можно достаточно простого `int`, или даже `char`. `putchar` работает в иную сотню раз быстрее.

Comment: @theoden  Какая вам скорость здесь нужна? Задание для начинающего программиста состоит в том, как я понимаю, чтобы просто аккуратно написать  посимвольный вывод файла на консоль. И чем вам не нравится size_t? Или вы считаете, что тип size_t более сложный, чем тип int?:) И что вы будете делать с типом char, если в задании изменится условие и вместо 60 знаков, нужно будет выводить, например, хотя бы 128 знаков,

Comment: `unsigned char` :)

Comment: Но вы правы, я просто хотел на всякий случай заметить такую невыгодную трату времени.

Comment: @theoden  Я думаю, это не тот случай, когда надо экономить на считанных байтах. Тем более, что это - локальная переменная предложения for.

Comment: писать нужно на С.

Comment: @Илья  В случае не нужно было включать метку C++, чтобы не вводить в заблуждение других участников темы. Однако в любом случае вы можете воспользоваться предоставленным кодом, так как вам важна реализация тела цикла, не так ли,? Просто включите его в свой код.,

Comment: Вывод будет в файл(после некоторой обработки массива). т.е мне в любом случае нужно заполнять массив.

Comment: @Илья Нужно формулировать задание таким образом, чтобы читающим его было понятно, что вам нужно. Из вашего же описания совершенно неясно, что конкретно вы хотите получить. Более того на комментарии к вопросу вы не отвечали.

Comment: Поясню что, мне нужно что бы именно массив заполнялся.
Извините, за неккоректность.

Comment: @Илья Тут также возникает вопрос: Если очередная строка в файле превышает размер буфера ввода, то нужно ли при ее разбивке на несколько строк массива вставлять в конец каждой строки массива  символ новой строки или это не обязательно?

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow, да перевод каретки нужен. При этом надо учитывать, что текст может быть различным например http://pastebin.com/rTM4DZL5

Comment: @Илья Попробуйте программу, приведенную в моем обновленном ответе.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow Спасибо! работает!